# Making a clickable Phone hyperlink in a Sharepoint contactlist

Tags: list, sharepoint, hyperlink, phone-number

I would like to make a `<a href:"TT:0123456789?Dial">` link in a Sharepoint foundation 2010 list. If I insert it in the column as a hyperlink/single item/rich text etc and hover on it, it respons like a link, but i cannot call with my Polycom (computer connected) VOIP phone. It will only click on the complete line.

I would really like to use the SP contactlist. What would be the solution to insert a clickable dial link?

Comment: [code]<a href:"TT:0123456789?Dial" .. [/code] Is the hyperlink I want to insert

Answer (score 0):

Your solution would be to create a custom field type for this. Crete a column type that, for example, displays a phone icon with your link on it. When you click your icon it will call instead of just mark the entire row. Read more about it [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms446361%28v=office.14%29.aspx).